# How to sort results with MS Dynamics Nav web services in PHP NTLM SOAP?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, microsoft-dynamics, ntlm

I'm able to get result and multiple results from page via an url, but I don't know how to sort multiple results by specific field.

```
stream_wrapper_unregister('http');
stream_wrapper_register('http', 'NTLMStream');

$service = new NTLMSoapClient($pageURL);
$params = [
    'filter' => [
        [
            'Field' => 'Type', 
            'Criteria' => 'blabla'
        ]
    ],
    'setSize' => 10
];
$result = $service->ReadMultiple($params); 
$resultSet = $result->ReadMultiple_Result->Item;

stream_wrapper_restore('http');
```

I tried the followings stuff :

```
$param['sortField'] = 'Date';
$param['orderField'] = 'Date';
$param['setSort'] = 'Date';
$param['setOrder'] = 'Date';
$param['sort'] = 'Date';
$param['order'] = 'Date';
$param['sort'] = [
    'Field' =>'Date',
    'Criteria' => 'ASC'
];
$param['order'] = [
    'Field' =>'Date',
    'Criteria' => 'ASC'
];
```

Nothing works, I don't know if it's only possible.

I don't found any complete documentation about Web Services with PHP for MS Dynamics Nav or which options are available as `param` other than `filter` and `setSize`

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the sorting on the page in dynamics NAV.